# cannot load shared library which exist on the library search path

Tags: linux, ld, autoconf, libtool, netfilter

I'm trying to execute nft , which was built from source , but it reports

```
 $ nft
nft: error while loading shared libraries: libnftnl.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I built libmnl,libnftnl,nftables from sources by runnning autogen.sh and then configuring with :

```
--prefix=/usr/local
```

these are the contents of /usr/local/lib :

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/lib/ | grep libnftnl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      961 Mar  2 20:16 libnftnl.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       17 Mar  2 20:16 libnftnl.so -> libnftnl.so.4.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       17 Mar  2 20:16 libnftnl.so.4 -> libnftnl.so.4.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   913147 Mar  2 20:16 libnftnl.so.4.0.0
```

more information :

```
$ ldd $(which nft)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd7afbf000)
    libmnl.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmnl.so.0 (0x00007fc60181f000)
    libnftnl.so.4 => not found
    libreadline.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 (0x00007fc6015d8000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007fc601364000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc600f9f000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007fc600d75000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055a0bd82d000)
```

and the contents of my ld.so.conf are :

```
$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot
# libc default configuration
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/lib/
# Multiarch support
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa
# Legacy biarch compatibility support
/lib32
/usr/lib32
# Legacy biarch compatibility support
/libx32
/usr/libx32
```

But if I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to '/usr/local/lib' :

```
 $ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
 $ ldd $(which nft)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffedf9b3000)
    libmnl.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libmnl.so.0 (0x00007fb58a033000)
    libnftnl.so.4 => /usr/local/lib/libnftnl.so.4 (0x00007fb589e0b000)
    libreadline.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 (0x00007fb589ba3000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007fb58992f000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb58956a000)
    libmxml.so.1 => /usr/lib/libmxml.so.1 (0x00007fb58935b000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb58913d000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007fb588f14000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055a827fb3000)
```

Can anybody help why it cannot find the library even if it exists in the search path ?

Comment: You probably need to re-run `ldconfig` as root after installing the library.

Comment: yes . It got resolved. Thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to run ldconfig , as pointed out by @Petesh . Problem got resolved after runnning ldconfig.